# 3d tick labels do not display correctly

Tags: matplotlib, mplot3d

I am plotting 3d bar plots using mplot3d:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

result=[[0, 0, 5, 5, 14,40,50],
[0, 1, 8, 9, 20,50,70],
[0, 2, 8, 10, 25,60,80],
[0, 5, 10, 20, 40,75,100]]

result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)
fig=plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(6, 4)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.view_init(25, 280)

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight']='normal'

xlabels = np.array(["Count1", "Count3","Count5", "Count6","Count7","Count8","Count9"])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(["5%","10%","20%","100%"])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos=result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx=0.75
dy=0.5
dz=zpos

ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx/2.)
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)

ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy/2)
ax1.set_yticklabels(ylabels)

ax1.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels(["","20%","40%","60%","80%","100%"])

colors = ['b','b','b','b','b','b','b','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','g','g','g','g','g','g','g']
ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz*0, dx, dy, dz, color=colors)
fig.savefig('tmp.tiff', dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

and here is what i got:

[image]

There are two problems here actually:

1) the y tick labels do not display correctly, they are supposed to be in the middle of the ticks but instead below the ticks. z tick labels are too close to the z ticks.

2) I suppose to use the font size 12 and the dpi should be higher than 300. I could not scale x axis such that the x tick labels fit nicely and do not overlap. I have tried multiply the xpos by 2. However the tick labels still overlap.

Comment: I don't think it can be helped w/o changing the font-size or the overall size of the image (then the effective font-size for your publication could be lowered w/o looking too small). When I adjust the fontsize slightly smaller all labels look very nicely placed.

Comment: I have tried to set  the font size like you said by:

for tick in ax1.w_zaxis.get_major_ticks():
  tick.label.set_fontsize(8)

or 

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'axes.titlesize': 8})
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'axes.labelsize': 8})
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'ytick.labelsize': 8})
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'xtick.labelsize': 8})

but it did not give me any effects at all.

Comment: I had only changed it in one location in your example `matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})` to `matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 9})` and it looked much better (Ipython,Jupyter, Python 2.7).

Comment: @roadrunner66 the same works for me. Additionally I would suggest adding to the `savefig` the parameter `bbox_inches='tight'` to remove margins.

Comment: @roadrunner66: running it on another machine work for me. imaluengo thanks for the suggestion.